# Invalid bind expression type of Integer for column of type String

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

```
 Integer BPcurrentYear = System.Today().year();
    List<Business_Plan__c> lBPs = [Select b.Year__c,  b.FCPA_Last_Updated__c, 
        (Select Name,IsHQ__c 
        FROM Business_Plan_Details__r WHERE Type__c = 'Current Year Revenue Goal') 
        FROM Business_Plan__c b WHERE Partner_Account__c = :accInstance.Id and b.Status__c = 'Approved' AND b.Year__c = :BPcurrentYear
        ORDER BY b.Year__c DESC ];
```

From abive query i'm getting error:

```
Invalid bind expression type of Integer for column of type String
```

I'm having problem with `b.Year__c = :BPcurrentYear`

Here the `b.Year__c` is Text Field. I am comparing with integer.

How to compare the Text field with integer or should i take take Current year in any other format which can assign to Text field?

Comment: String.valueOf may help you to get current year as string

Comment: yes i did this Datetime dt = Datetime.NOW();
        string BPcurrentYear = String.valueOf(dt.year());                                                               Now it is working. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `String` value for `Year__c` field:

`String  BPcurrentYear= String.valueOf(system.today().year());`